# Should a nugget ever shift the variogram away from zero at distance zero?

Tags: spatial, variogram

I had frequently seen the definition for a "rigorous" spatial isotropic semivariogram being defined as:

$$
\gamma(h) = K(0) - K(h)
$$

Where $K$ is a positive definite covariance matrix. If the nugget $\sigma$ is applied to the covariance function $K$, then it seems to me that it would always be that $\gamma(0) = 0$, but that $\gamma(0+\delta)>\sigma$ for all distances greater than zero.

However, often in practice a linear function is used to determine $\gamma$:

$$
\gamma(h) = \sigma + \frac{h}{\beta}
$$

Should I really define the nugget in terms of the covariance matrix, or should I make it a separate term:

$$
\gamma(h) = \sigma + K(0) - K(h)
$$

Am I making a mountain out of mole hill here? Are there any reasons to prefer one form or the other?

To visualize, is it more "correct" to pick one form over the other:

[image: nonzero zero]

[image: zero zero]

Based on the idea of nugget as allowing a non-zero offset at zero, I could see the former should be preferred: but this seems to imply that the nugget is no really part of the assumed covariance matrix.

Comment: I don't have an answer, but I think that this question is related to mine: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/551359/what-is-the-difference-between-a-non-zero-nugget-and-a-noise-term-in-kriging-gpr